# How to remove amounts in thousands in Telerik WPF RadChart?

Tags: wpf, telerik, bar-chart, radchart

Using RadChart is assigned at runtime to the same data through a dataset, the result of a database query.

Through code (vb.net) created the series and other settings needed in a conventional bar graph.

**The problem:**
When values ​​are thousands, the value is represented by a "K". Example: If the value is 1658, the bar shows 1.66 K.

**question:**
  How to remove the value of "K" and express the number unchanged as it gets?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try following to remove it

```
RadChart1.DefaultView.ChartArea.LabelFormatBehavior = LabelFormatBehavior.None;
```

For More options please refer to this [link](http://www.telerik.com/help/silverlight/t_telerik_windows_controls_charting_labelformatbehavior.html), I hope this would help.

Comment: Excellent!! It works....Do you know how to format that number, complete now? .....

That is, show 1.569 instead of 1569